# How to exit from loop when find matched parameter in java

Tags: java, arraylist

Assume that I have an ArrayList containing 5 data as follows:

`testarrar=[optio1, option2, option3, realdata, option5];`

I want to iterate over the above list and if i get **realdata**, then collect respective data, but in my case the code further excute after **realdata** and returns null.

**Edited:**

> my Intention in my method if found realdata then i want to return data
>   otherwise i dont want to return any value from this method. but in my case it 
>   at least null if data notfound.So that , I am trying to returning value if realdata
>   found and exit.but my function  goes end of testarrar.Only this function call if data have.

here is my code:

```
private Object getData() {
          if (testarrar.contains("realdata"))
        {
            if (obj != null) {
                //do something and get data
                return b.getValue(data);// I want to exit when matched parameter return this value
            }

        } 

        return null; // I am getting this
    }
```

**If realdata in last then it work but any of position except last then return null, because it assume realdata in last. how to solve this, if i have any position realdata.**

Comment: Which loop? There are no loops in your code.

Comment: If you use `return`, the `loop` will be terminated when the record is found!

Comment: Ok, I have no loop, how to exit from this carrying respective data. btw why returning null from this method.

Comment: You mean: you alway get null value although you array contain data?

Comment: You can use break; statement.

Comment: what is obj? Very much unclear what you are asking.Please elaborate clearly.

Comment: Could you please provide a clear and more expressive example of your code? There is a lot of information missing. What is obj, where comes b from etc. pp.

Comment: use break statemant .

Comment: @user2332049 please post the complete code

Comment: where is the definition of `testarrar`, and where is the point where string containing `realdata` is being inserted into it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use 'break' for exiting the loop like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<testarrar.length;i++){
 if(testarrar.get(i)=="realdata"){
 //do your stuff;
 break;
 }
}
```

if you want to return the data and exit the loop, use return as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i<testarrar.length;i++){
 if(testarrar.get(i)=="realdata"){
 //do your stuff;
 return data;
 }
}
```

return will automatically exit the loop and send the data back to function call.

in your case, remove the

```
return null;
```

statement and check whether you're still getting null or not.
cause the value of

`b.getValue(data);` 
which you're returning might be null.

Comment: This is not work. `This method must return a result of type Object`. but   not get return value. I am getting value if realdata occurs but my last option 5 execute so it get return null.

Comment: You can check the type of retuned value in your code, if it is an object you can proceed and if it is null you can ignore.
If you really need an object of some sort to be returned, instead of returning null return the  object of whatever-type you want to return.
`Object obj = new Object();
return obj`